# How can I save an GStreamer RTSP stream of unknown type to a file

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, v4l2

I'm using this Gstreamer pipeline to send an RTSP stream of a camera.

```bash
./gst-rtsp-launch --port 8554 "( v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,width=640,height=480 ! rtpvrawpay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

I want to using `playbin`, so I don't need to specify the type of video from the rtsp stream. If I use this pipeline, I can get a single image from the camera:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://(ip-of-camera):8554 video-sink="jpegenc ! filesink location=capture1.jpeg"
```

But if I try this pipeline, to save as a file:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://(ip-of-camera):8554 video-sink="videoconvert ! video/x-h264,width=320,height=240 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4"
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1: Internal data stream error.
Additional information for debugging:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc1:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.094968753
Defining the processing queue to NULL...
Freeing the processing queue...
```

*Note: I had translate the last two lines.*

Is there a problem in the pipeline I'm using to save the stream as a file?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your pipeline and in worked.

I only added -e after gst-launch-1.0, so that GStreamer writes all necessary information to the file when ctrl-C is pressed:

gst-launch-1.0 -e playbin uri=(rtsp url) video-sink="videoconvert ! video/x-h264,width=320,height=240 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4"

Maybe you are using an older version of GStreamer?
I am using GStreamer 1.20.0

Comment: I was indeed using an older version. Using Gstreamer 1.18.4, I got the error "Element missing: JPEG decoder". If I use decodebin and matroskamux on rtspsrc it finally works.